# Copy File in eclipse copies file name (String) instead of file to clipboard

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, clipboard

Having some issues with Eclipse here.

For some unknown reason when I try to copy a file from one directory to another, instead of placing the file to the clipboard it just copies the file name (a String).

What happens when I then paste it to the new directory is it creates a file called Snippet.java with the file name string in this class.

Has anyone else seen this sort of behaviour before?

Edit: Nevermind guys, rebooting my machine seemed to fix the problem. Who knows what was going on there.

Comment: Nope, I've never had that problem.

Comment: I've seen it before... don't remember how I fixed it though.

Comment: see the first answer about Skype Click to call. I actually removed the chrome extension.

Answer (score 7):

I have the exact problem as described by Jake Mackay and have battled with it for several hours on the grounds that copying files is fundamental to the proper use of Eclipse.

Firstly I don't think it's an Eclipse problem as I have a similar problem in Eclipse Europa and Indigo.  Also starting windows (7 service pack 1) in safe mode the problem goes away.

In my case I have narrowed the problem down to having the "Skype Click to Call v 5.10.0.9560" extension installed in "Google Chrome v 18.0.1025.168 m".  When Google Chrome is not running or running with the extension disabled the problem goes away.  From this I presume that Skype Click to Call is intercepting key board and mouse events for "cut/copy" and changing the normal behaviour.

For me installing the latest version of click to call, at this time v 5.11.0.9874 the problem also goes away.

Comment: Thanks, disabling "Skype click to call" from google chrome worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before, in Eclipse have you tried going to `Window>Preferences>General` and under `General` go to `Keys`

Find the Copy under the Command column, and change the value in the When column to In Dialogs and Windows.